# Do static methods in a C# .NET Singleton class have a negative effect on performance or memory consumption?

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, static-methods

As a simple example, say I have a C# singleton class as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public sealed class RestrictedNameCollection : List<string>
{
    private static object _lock = new object();

    private RestrictedNameCollection()
    {
    }

    private static RestrictedNameCollection _instance;
    public static RestrictedNameCollection Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        var nameList = new List<string>();
                        nameList.Add("Jack");
                        nameList.Add("Jill");
                        nameList.Add("John");
                        nameList.Add("Jane");

                        var restrictedNameCollection = new RestrictedNameCollection();
                        foreach (var name in nameList)
                        {
                            restrictedNameCollection.Add(name);
                        }

                        _instance = restrictedNameCollection;
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I can add an `IsRestrictedName(string name)` method to the class the following 2 ways.

```
public bool IsRestrictedName(string name)
{
    return Contains(name);
}
```

Or:

```
public static bool IsRestrictedName(string name)
{
    return Instance.Contains(name);
}
```

I can use the first version by calling `RestrictedNameCollection.Instance.IsRestrictedName("Jack")`. But I prefer being to able to call the second version `RestrictedNameCollection.IsRestrictedName("Jack")` for it's brevity.

My question is, is there any reason that I should stay away from the static version of the method? Is this purely a syntactic debate? Or are there underlying performance implications that I should be concerned with?

Comment: You can't call the instance method at all without knowing the instance.  Which requires using the Instance property getter.  So you'll pay for it either way.  At least move the if() statement body into a separate method so the property getter can be inlined.  And if it really, really matter then use a static constructor instead.

Comment: Then, why do you use a singleton instead of a static class?

Answer (score 0):

The memory question is a bit tricky, but basically once you have called it once, all the data ("jack" etc) will be loaded into memory and will stay until the dll unloads.  On performance, I would worry more about thread safety.  However.. to the point I wanted to make.. why are you going through all this effort to populate a list? Just make a couple static functions like "populatenames" and "populaterestricted"?

I think you are over-thinking this....

Comment: Trey, I wrote the example just for the post here so that I could focus on the difference between the methods. The real world singleton that inspired this is actually much more complex, but I simplified it for readability's sake. In all the singleton examples I see the internal methods are typically accessed by calling Instance.Whatever(), so I am curious as to why or if static methods that access the instance should be avoided inside the singleton class itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried making a [simple fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eK8Q1X) to test the performance difference. Like you, I hoped that a singleton accessed through static methods would be as good (maybe better) than a pure static class. Now, while it *may* be better under different conditions, my results seem to show that there isn't a very significant difference, although the pure singleton seems to more often than not come in slower than the a static-method singleton or a static class.

Not the most conclusive test, but it reassures me that any preferred version is probably alright.